# Stack and recursive function Maximum call stack size exceeded how to solve while keeping recursion?

Tags: node.js, recursion, stack-overflow, settimeout

I add this as a question answer wiki since I ran into this a couple of times.

This time it was for a line reader and processor that could be fed with a large array or line by line from a stream.

Since getLine would call lineHandler and lineHandler would call getLine there would be a problem with the stack getting too big when processing hundreds of thousands of lines.

To solve this I use setTimeout to wipe out the call stack instead of directly calling the functions. Here is some sample code:

```
function startPromise(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      resolve();
  })
}
var lineCount=0;
var totalLines=2000000;
var totalCount=0;
var linesProcessed=0;
function processFile(){console.log('we are done');}
function lineHandler(){
  if(linesProcessed%100===0){
    console.log('processed:',linesProcessed);
  }
  lineCount++;
  linesProcessed++;
  setTimeout(getLine,0);
  return;
}
function getLine(){
 startPromise()
  .then(function(){
    if(lineCount>=totalLines){
      setTimeout(processFile,0);
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(lineHandler,0);
  })
  .then(null,function(error){//failed to process this line
    console.log('fail:',error);
  })
}
getLine();
```

Because of the 2 timeouts in every line this code runs very slow (100 lines in a second). This is way too slow because I'm hoping to process 10 million in an Hour.

Comment: Your title fails to ask a question that intends to solve a problem. Instead, you're asking how make your proposed solution work when an entirely different solution might be altogether better. See more: [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

Answer (score 0):

I replaced all setTimeout calls with speedup and the speedup function is like the following:

```
var speedup = (function() {
  var stack=0;
  return function(fn,t){
    stack++;
    //if call stack gets over 5000 then do a setTimeout
    //  to reset the stack
    if(stack%5000===0){
      setTimeout(fn,t);
      stack=0;
    }else{
      fn();
    }
  };
}())
```

**[update]**

With native Promise there is no need to use setTimeout to control the execution flow and keep the stack short. Some libraries may not break out or use setTimeout (=slow down) but tried the code without setTimeout and did not run out of stack space even with 50000 recursions.

Comment: This does not seem like the proper solution for whatever it is you're working on. It looks like a stream would be a much better solution for this.

Comment: @naomik Thank you for your reply, the lineProcessor can be used with several things, a huge array is one of them. You suggest I should convert that into a stream or iterator (something like having a while(lines.next()))? At the moment I'm using recursion because it gives me the opportunity to replace lineHandler and getLine functions.

Comment: can you give an example of input and expected output ?

Comment: @naomik, input can come from file, http post or large array. It is up to getLine implementation from where. The line is given to a lineHandler function that will use a documentFactory that has a toString method generating csv line, json or xml output. The lineHandler will send the processed line to a send function that can return an object indicating the lineHandler should pause. If that is the case then lineHanler should call getLine every half a second until send returns continue. The sample code is stripped of all that.

Comment: Because of all this complexity I decided getLine should call a lineHandler that will call getLine when done. Send can fail but it's up to send to log this failure. getLine and lineHandler should get lines and give to send as fast as send allows it to.